# Show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x) F(dx)=\frac{1}{2}$ if $F$ is a continuous distribution function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

If $F$ is a continuous distribution function, prove that 
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x) F(dx)=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

**What I tried**

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x) F(dx)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} P(X \le x) F(dx)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} E[\mathsf{1}_{X \le x}]F(dx)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}  \int_\Omega \mathsf{1}_{X \le x} dP F(dx)\\
&=  \int_\Omega  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathsf{1}_{X \le x} F(dx) dP 
\end{align*}
where the last step is due to Fubini's theorem.
If the above is correct what to do next? Thanks

Comment: I'm not completely sure of the meaning of your notation, but it looks like this is a job for integration by parts.

Comment: could you elaborate more?

Comment: What is $F(dx)$? Is it the Lebesgue–Stieltjes measure with respect to the cdf $F(x)$?

Comment: @Xiao Yes it is ...

Comment: The accepted (and upvoted...) solution depends on the **false** premise that every continuous CDF is differentiable. Not so, as easy examples show.

Comment: @Did Monotone functions are differentiable a.e. is a standard result from Lebesgue theory.

Comment: @Xiao If you want to invoke a standard result, please invoke it correctly. I read in your answer that F is differentiable and this is just *wrong* (and if ever this escaped you when you typed your answer, now you know it hence you should work to make your answer acceptable (in the mathematical sense, not in the MSE sense) instead of ergoting).

Comment: @Did Thank you for your instructive and constructive comments.

Comment: @Xiao You are welcome, always at your service. By the way, what happens to your argument if F is the Cantor function, the well known (since you like the phrase) CDF with derivative zero almost everywhere?

Comment: Good call. The my first solution would not work for cantor function, since cantor measure is singular w.r.t the lebesgue measure. I will edit it when i get to a computer.

Comment: @Xiao It is a bit unfortunate that one has to fight against your systematic stonewalling when making obvious points about basic mistakes in your posts (that there exists nondifferentiable CDFs being not exactly cutting edge science). Various cranks are known on the site for this stick-to-ones-guns-at-all-costs approach but you might wish to change the attitude for yourself, if you wish to be taken seriously. (And use @.)

Comment: @Did What was the point of your last comment? Above that I did say you were correct, and I did agree with your counter example to my argument.

Comment: @Xiao The point of my last comment is to mention that I find unfortunate to have to fight against systematic stonewalling and that this stick-to-ones-guns-at-all-costs approach, known to be adopted by various cranks on the site, was not something you would want your name attached to. Clearer now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration#Integration_by_parts) to show the following
$$
  I = \int_\Bbb R F(x)\mathrm dF(x) = F^2(x)|^\infty_{-\infty} - \int_\Bbb R F(x)\mathrm dF(x) = 1-I\implies I = \frac12
$$

Since Xiao provided another solution, I'll think it's worth telling you about a third one which is a neat probabilistic one-liner. Since $X$ is continuous, $F(X)\sim U[0,1]$ and hence your integral is an expectation of a uniformly distributed random variable on $[0,1]$ which is of course $\frac12$.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Do you know of the proof that would you Fubini's theorem?

Comment: @Boby: I don't think it leads anywhere, we can't really make use of the indicator function since it can't be passed to be the limits of the outer integral.

Comment: @Boby: I've added another proof.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution that I think you are looking for, recall from your other problem
$$\int_\Omega f(x) dP = \int_0^\infty P\big(\{f>t\}\big) dt,$$
observe that $\mu_F$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$, so let $\Omega := \mathbb{R}$ and $P:= \mu_F$, we get 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x) d\mu_F = \int_0^\infty \mu_F\big(\{F>t\}\big) dt =\int_0^1 \mu_F\big(\{F>t\}\big) dt,$$
because for $t>1$, the set $\{F>t\}$ is an empty set, thus $\mu_F\big(\{F>t\}\big)=0$ .

And for $t\in [0,1]$, I claim that $\mu_F\big(\{F>t\}\big) = 1-t$.

Here notice that since $F$ is a cdf, thus it is monotone, then the set $\{F>t\}$ is an interval $(r, \infty)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. (When $F$ is strictly increasing, then $F$ is invertable and we can take $r = F^{-1}(t)$). From the definition of L-S measure on intervals and $F$ is continuous, we have 
$$\mu_F((r, \infty)) = F(\infty) - F(r) = 1-t$$
then 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x) d\mu_F =\int_0^1 1-t\;dt = 1/2.$$

Comment: "Since $F(x)$ is a cdf, we know $F(x)$ is actually differentiable" You probably mean to say that "since $F$ is a cdf, we know $F$ is differentiable" but, *actually* we know nothing of the sort. It is unfortunate that the rest of your solution depends on this.

Comment: @Did Monotone functions are differentiable a.e. is a standard result from Lebesgue theory.

Comment: If you want to invoke a standard result, please invoke it correctly. I read in your answer that $F$ is differentiable and this is just *wrong*.

Comment: "the derivative is the pdf function" Sorry, but wrong again (the existence of a PDF is not guaranteed).

Comment: The answer was (silently) thoroughly rewritten and is now closer to be satisfying. A point which still needs to be clarified, though, is the argument to show that $\mu_F(F\gt t)=t$ for every $t$ holds in full generality, even when $F$ is not increasing everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{E}[F(X)]&=\int_{\Omega}F(X(\omega))P(d\omega)\\&=\int_{{\mathbb{R}}}F(x)(P\circ X^{-1})(dx)\\&=\int_{{\mathbb{R}}}\mathrm{Pr}(X\leq x)(P\circ X^{-1})(dx)\\
 &=\int_{{\mathbb{R}}}\mathrm{E}[1(X\leq x)](P\circ X^{-1})(dx)\\
 &=\int_{{\mathbb{R}}}\int_{\Omega}1(X(\omega)\leq x)P(d\omega)(P\circ X^{-1})(dx)\\
 &=\int_{\Omega}\int_{{\mathbb{R}}}1(X(\omega)\leq x)(P\circ X^{-1})(dx)P(d\omega)\tag{Fubini’s Theorem}\\
 &=\int_{\Omega}\bigg(1-\mathrm{Pr}(x\leq X(\omega))\bigg)P(d\omega)\\
 &=1-\mathrm{E}[F(X)].
 \end{align*}