# Show $E(X)= \int_{[0, \infty)} P[X>t] dt$, without using density argument

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

For $X$, a positive random variable, use Fubini's theorem applied to $\sigma$-finite measure to prove

\begin{align*}
E(X)= \int_{[0, \infty)} P[X>t] dt
\end{align*}

I found several references on the the site like this:

1. [Proving $EX=\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-F(x))\, dx$ when $X\geq0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262088/proving-ex-int-0-infty1-fx-dx-when-x-geq0)
2. [Expression for $n$-th moment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158206/expression-for-n-th-moment)

but all of them assume that $X$ has density or discrete is the are different proof that does not use this assumption.

**This is what I tried**

\begin{align*}
\int_{[0, \infty)} P[X>t] dt&= \int_{[0, \infty)} E(\mathsf{1}_{[X>t]}) dt=\int_{[0, \infty)} \int_{\Omega} \mathsf{1}_{[X>t]}dP dt\\
 &=\int_{\Omega} \int_{[0, \infty)} \mathsf{1}_{[X>t]} dt dP=\int_{\Omega} \int_{[0, X)} 1 dt dP=\int_{\Omega} X dP=E[X]
\end{align*}
where the first step in second line is due to Fubinni's theorem

Comment: Try to rewrite $P[X>t]$ as an integral of $\chi_{\{X>t\}}$, then Fubini's theorem will apply naturally. Also observe that $$\int_0^\infty \chi_{\{X>t\}}(x) dt = \int_0^{X(x)} 1 dt.$$

Comment: Dear, @Xiao I just made editions is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that is what Xiao meant.

Comment: @Boby Nicely done.

Comment: @Xiao thanks for you help. If you want please submit an answer and I will give credit it

Comment: That's okay, glad to help!

Comment: Dear @Xiao, I was working on differnt problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048718/show-that-int-mathbbr-fx-fdx-frac12-if-f-is-a-continuous-dist I think it requires the same approach could you take a look? thanks